# How to get site data

Tags: analytics

I have a site that features other websites, and displayed details. Now I want to get more information about the sites I feature like page views, visits, etc.

How do I do that? Is there an API for it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, information about how many visits, pageviews, etc. other websites have is generally not publicly available, because (obviously) many companies / website owners don't want to share that information and there's no general-purpose way of getting it.

That said, here's list of websites which attempt to display that kind of information:

- [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com)
- [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com)
- [Compete.com](http://www.compete.com)
- [Google Ad Planner](http://www.google.com/adplanner/)

I'm sure there are others, but these are the ones I'm familiar with. Some of them have APIs, but you should keep in mind that none of them provide accurate data, but only estimates, simply because exact numbers are unknown unless published by the website owner.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google Analytics. It can give you information about visits, pageviews, trends, used webbrowers, screen resolutions and many more!

Comment: He's after the site data of sites not under his control. Hence third-party services that attempt to gauge (or guess) these values.